# How to show autocomplete inside textbox / textarea / textinput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using `antd` UI library for my project, I am trying to show an autocomplete inside a `textarea` only for a word that user types. But antd doesn't seem to support that particular feature.

I tried to use the default autocomplete feature in `antd / Html5` but no luck

I tried the below example

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { AutoComplete, Input } from 'antd';

const { TextArea } = Input;

function onSelect(value) {
  console.log('onSelect', value);
}

class Complete extends React.Component {
  state = {
    dataSource: ['test', 'hello'],
  };

  handleSearch = value => {
    // this.setState({
    //   dataSource: !value ? [] : [value, value , value ],
    // });
  };

  handleKeyPress = ev => {
    console.log('handleKeyPress', ev);
  };

  render() {
    const { dataSource } = this.state;
    return (
      <AutoComplete
        dataSource={dataSource}
        style={{ width: 200 }}
        onSelect={onSelect}
        onSearch={this.handleSearch}
      >
        <TextArea
          placeholder="input here"
          className="custom"
          style={{ height: 50 }}
          onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
        />
      </AutoComplete>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Complete />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

I want to override this behavior or create an own autocomplete to show inside the textinput `without jquery`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define the possible auto complete values in an array and pass it to `AutoComplete` as the `dataSource` value. The example generates the autocomplete values dynamically but you don't need to do that. Here's an example of how you might provide possible autocomplete values [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/lively-star-yo0gr)